# Laravel(5.3.24+) Validation: Custom Validation with Custom Error Message

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

Custom error message not working for custom rule, see variable $messages uniqueTeamNameForcomp.

Custom rule is fine, custom message for rule:required is fine also.

The error message that shows for the rule uniqueTeamNameForComp is "unique_team_name_for_comp" when it should be reading the error message "This name already exist for this competition".

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $rules = [
        'name'      => 'required|uniqueTeamNameForComp:'.$request->compzid,
        'compz'     => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = array(
        'uniqueTeamNameForComp' => 'This name already exist for this competition',
        'required'              => 'this works'
    );

    $this->validate($request,$rules,$messages);

}
```

SERVICE PROVIDER:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('uniqueTeamNameForComp', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $competitionId = $parameters[0];

        return count(Tteam::where("comp_id", "=", $competitionId)->whereName($value)->get()) == 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `'unique:tteams,name,NULL,id,comp_id,'.$request->compzid` That will require the name to be unique for records with a comp_id equal to `$request->compzid` and ignore records with an ID of null (that last part is there just because of the parameter order of the [unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're seeing from Laravel is actually giving you a hint. It expects the custom messages to be keyed by the validation rule in snake case, not camel case.

```
$messages = array(
    'unique_team_name_for_comp' => 'This name already exist for this competition',
    'required'                  => 'this works'
);
```